# How to fix a magento cookie?

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

The cookies of my magento store are expiring after a successful checkout. The session desapears and some css and js files become unreacheble by the browser.

Can someone point me to a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I recently had similar problem.  And it was fixed by increasing the "Cookie Lifetime" to 1 day (86400) and explicitly setting the `"Cookie Path" to "/"`

Both changes can be made at **Admin->Configuration->Web->Session Cookie Management**